# Access the sum of multiple arrays in React

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

```
const App = () => {
  const course = [{
    id: 1,
    name: 'Half Stack application development',
    parts: [
      {
        name: 'Fundamentals of React',
        exercises: 10,
        id: 1
      },
      {
        name: 'Using props to pass data',
        exercises: 7,
        id: 2
      },
      {
        name: 'State of a component',
        exercises: 14,
        id: 3
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    name: 'Node.js',
    id: 2,
    parts: [
      {
        name: 'Routing',
        exercises: 3,
        id: 1
      },
      {
        name: 'Middlewares',
        exercises: 7,
        id: 2
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

I am trying to calculate the sum of the exercises in each of the courses so I can get something at the end of each course which says Total exercises: 31 at the end of Half Stack Application Development and total exercises 10: at the end of Node.Js

I have tried

```
const totals = course.map(c => c.parts.map(c => c.exercises.map(c => c.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0))))
```

but received c.exercises.map is not a function.

How could I calculate the sum of each of c.exercises?

exercises looks like this in the console:

```
(2) [Array(3), Array(2)]
0: (3) [10, 7, 14]
1: (2) [3, 7]
length: 2
```

Answer (score 0):

This to calculate just the number of exercises per course

```js
const calculateTotalExercises = course =>
  course.map(c => c.parts.reduce((res, {
    exercises
  }) => res + exercises, 0))

const course = [{
    id: 1,
    name: 'Half Stack application development',
    parts: [{
        name: 'Fundamentals of React',
        exercises: 10,
        id: 1
      },
      {
        name: 'Using props to pass data',
        exercises: 7,
        id: 2
      },
      {
        name: 'State of a component',
        exercises: 14,
        id: 3
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    name: 'Node.js',
    id: 2,
    parts: [{
        name: 'Routing',
        exercises: 3,
        id: 1
      },
      {
        name: 'Middlewares',
        exercises: 7,
        id: 2
      }
    ]
  }
]

console.log(calculateTotalExercises(course))
```

Probably it will be more convenient to add the total of the exercise to the array like this

```js
const calculateTotalExercises = course =>
  course.map(c => ({...c, totalExercise : c.parts.reduce((res, p) => res + p.exercises, 0)}))

const course = [{
    id: 1,
    name: 'Half Stack application development',
    parts: [{
        name: 'Fundamentals of React',
        exercises: 10,
        id: 1
      },
      {
        name: 'Using props to pass data',
        exercises: 7,
        id: 2
      },
      {
        name: 'State of a component',
        exercises: 14,
        id: 3
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    name: 'Node.js',
    id: 2,
    parts: [{
        name: 'Routing',
        exercises: 3,
        id: 1
      },
      {
        name: 'Middlewares',
        exercises: 7,
        id: 2
      }
    ]
  }
]

console.log(calculateTotalExercises(course))
```

Comment: I'm sorry but this just produces a number that says "3110" - do you have any idea how to render this into a component where it would look like this:      Half Stack application development 
Fundamentals of React: 10
Using props to pass data: 7
State of a component: 14
TOTAL EXERCISES: 31
Node.js
Routing: 3
Middlewares: 7
TOTAL EXERCISES 10
At the moment I am getting 
Fundamentals of React: 10
Using props to pass data: 7
State of a component: 14
3110
Node.js
Routing: 3
Middlewares: 7
3110

Comment: it's an array with 2 element, one for each course `[31, 10]`

Comment: @JuliusGoddard I added another answer that I think will be more usefull in your case

Answer (score 0):

You could start by breaking the problem down. Here's how I solved this.

I created a function that finds the total number of exercises for one course

```
let totalExerciseForOneCourse = (parts) => {
  return parts.reduce((prev, curr) => prev + curr.exercises, 0)
}
```

Then we use the map method to go through each ***course*** in the ***courses*** array returning a new array of objects with everything that was in the ***courses*** array and adding in a ***totalExercises*** object property

```
let newCourses = courses.map((course) => {
  const total = totalExerciseForOneCourse(course.parts);
  return Object.assign({}, course, {
    totalExercises: total
  })
})
```

Our ***totalExerciseForOneCourse*** function takes an array parameter and calculates the sum of all exercises for one course using the **array.reduce** method

***newCourses*** contains our new array with all previous and new information

JSFiddle  -

> https://jsfiddle.net/swish933/9fwzysxa/

Comment: I get "Cannot read the properties of undefined" reading 'reduce' when trying this.

Comment: Make sure you are passing the array  _**course.parts**_ to the  _**totalExerciseForOneCourse**_ function  .I suggest you take a look at the fiddle link.

Answer (score 0):

The sum of multiple arrays can be rendered in a single component looking like this

```
{c.parts.reduce((a, b) => a += b.exercises, 0)}
```

Comment: You should probably elaborate your answer, at least explain what is `c`.

Answer (score -1):

You can just do

```
let total = 0

courses.map(course => course.parts.map(part => total += part.exercises)
```

**Edit:**
Just in case you need to use reduce:

```
const total = courses.map(course => course.parts.reduce(e1,e2 => e1+e2 ))
```